# ¿Como saber el valor de un array compararlo con una variable?

Tags: php, array, php7, arraylist, array-bidimensional

lo que trato de hacer es recorrer un array multidimensional en php, y necesito sumar los valores de una posicion en especifica y ver durante la suma cual se acerca más al valor de una variable ya definida.

```
      <?php
    $camion = 700;
    $peso = array(
        array('Lola', 360, '40'),
        array('Maria', 250, '35'),
        array('adi', 400, '43'),
        array('Sandy', 180, '28'),
        array('nena', 50, '12'),
        array('Yoko', 90, '13'),
    );

?>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center m-5">
   <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3><?= ('Relación peso producción') ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="dt-responsive table-responsive">
                    <table id="alt-pg-dt" class="table table-striped nowrap">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                                <th scope="col">Peso</th>
                                <th scope="col">Producción</th>
                                <!--th scope="col">Cálculo</th-->
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <?php for ($i=0; $i<count($peso); $i++):
                                    for($j=0; $j<count($peso[$i]); $j++):?>
                                        <td><?= $peso[$i][$j] ?> </td>
                                    <?php endfor; ?>
                                    <!--td><?= $calculo = $camion - $peso[$i][1] ?> </td-->
                            </tr>
                                <?php endfor; ?>
                        </tbody>
                        
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

$camion es la variable definida.
$peso es el arreglo multidimesional.

deberia recorrer el array, verificar o utilizar la posicion [1] del array, que es donde estan los primeros números y luego de sumarlos no pasar del valor de la variable. pero debo saber cual combinación en las posiciones se acerca más a la variable.

No se, si me explique bien.
Espero puedan orientarme y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: No te he explicaste bien. Pulsa en [edit] y clarifica tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver este problema debes recorrer el arreglo con un foreach, te creas par de variables de control y en el foreach vas preguntando por cada índice el valor que me imagino que por tu ejemplo está en el segundo valor ósea el índice[1] luego simplemente con un if vas preguntando si es mayor o no la suma de lo que has agregado en el arreglo que creamos de control llamado $personas_a_llevar

```
$personas_a_llevar = array();
$peso_total = 0;

foreach ($peso as $persona) {
    if ($peso_total + $persona[1] <= $camion) {
        $personas_a_llevar[] = $persona[0];
        $peso_total += $persona[1];
    }
}

echo "Vas a llevar a -> : " . implode(", ", $personas_a_llevar);
```

IMPORTANTE: Si quieres montar en el camión el mayor número de personas ordena de menor a mayor el arreglo por el peso y cuando tengas el camión lleno puedes llamar el otro camión, recuerda que debes controlar el peso que soportaría cada camión, y luego montarías los que quedan, si lo dejas como esta el programa va ha recorrer todo el arreglo pero si comienzas con un valor grande solo montarías menos gente.

El resultado aquí sería Lola, Maria y Nena, fijate que salto el de 400 y 180 porque se pasaba y continuo con otro que si podía, pero si hubieras comenzado con 400 de "adi" quedaría solo 300 en peso por montar.